# SQL Query to ignore similar rows from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that consists of logs and timestamps, for example:

```
timestmp    log_error
1507031197631   Er7
1507031197621   Er8
1507031197409   Er9
1506888444602   Er10
1506880074401   Er10
1506880047684   Er10
1506880030996   Er10
1506879980929   Er10
1506879977580   Er10
1506879974250   Er10
1506879970901   Er10
1506879964241   Er10
1506879954212   Er10
1506879900817   Er10
```

I want to write a SQL query that ignores same consecutive errors (in this case, Er10) within some interval of timestamp (5 minutes). How can I accomplish this? Using a self Inner Join? The result I want is something like this:

```
timestmp    log_error
1507031197631   Er7
1507031197621   Er8
1507031197409   Er9
1506888444602   Er10 /* The last one from this example, based on the difference in timestmp */
1506879900817   Er10 /* The first Er10 registry */
```

Comment: pls. tag the DBMS (MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle) which u r using.

Comment: @YogeshSharma, tagged, thanks.

Comment: throw proper sample data so that timestmp    column can be converted to datetime.or throw data with datetime column.then only we can find data of 5 minute interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `lag()`, cumulative sum, and `group by`:

```
select log_error, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select l.*,
             sum(case when prev_le = log_error and
                           prev_timestamp > timestamp - "5 minutes"
                      then 0 else 1
                 end) over (order by timestamp) as grp
      from (select l.*,
                   lag(log_error) over (order by timestmp) as prev_le,
                   lag(timestmp) over (order by timestmp) as prev_timestmp
            from logs l
           ) l
     ) l
group by grp, log_error;
```

Note:  The `- "5 minutes"` is intended to be whatever the logic is for that.  Presumably, this is either `5 * 60` or `5 * 60 * 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number to make groups of consecutive log_error values. This method is called "tabibitosan method"

```
select log_error, min(timestmp), max(timestmp)
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over (order by timestmp)
        - row_number() over (partition by log_error order by timestmp) as grp
    from your_table t
    ) t
group by log_error, grp;
```

I admit that the result format is not exactly how you wanted it, but it has the information you need.